# Highcharts setting wrong translate position for bar dataLabels

Tags: javascript, highcharts, ember.js

I'm using Highcharts to display a bar chart, and a dataLabels at the left for positive value and left for negative value. as shown in below image

The problem here is that when the bar data value is big, the label is not displayed from the chart into the frame, going over outside frame , and making them both unreadable.

[image]
Here are my plotOptions :

```
chart: {
        type: 'bar',
        height: 60,
        events: {
          render: this.chartRendered.bind(this),
          load: this.chartLoaded.bind(this),
          redraw: this.chartRedraw.bind(this),
          click: this.chartClicked.bind(this),
          selection: this.chartZoomed.bind(this),
        },
      },
      title: {
        text: '',
      },
      exporting: {
        enabled: false,
      },
      xAxis: [
        {
          visible: false,
          reversed: false,
          labels: {
            enabled: false,
          },
          gridLineWidth: 0,
        },
        {
          // mirror axis on right side
          visible: false,
          opposite: true,
          reversed: false,
          linkedTo: 0,
          labels: {
            enabled: false,
          },
          gridLineWidth: 0,
        },
      ],
      yAxis: {
        title: {
          text: '',
        },
        labels: {
          enabled: false,
        },
        visible: false,
        gridLineWidth: 0,
        gridLineColor: 'transparent',
        min: -25,
        max: 25,
      },
      plotOptions: {
        series: {
          stacking: 'normal',
          pointWidth: 40,
        },
    dataLabels: {
                  align: 'right',
                  enabled: true,
                  color: 'black',
                  x: 45,
                },
      },
      tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
          return `<b>${this.series.name}: ${this.point.y} ${this.series.userOptions.uom}</b>`;
        },
      },
      legend: {
        enabled: false,
      },
    };
```

It showing perfectly for smaller bar, but not for bigger bar.

I inspected highchart in browser console, highchart setting translate (0, -9999) for dataLabels in bigger bar.
[image]

Comment: Hi @Manny_s, I am not able to reproduce the problem with the provided options. Could you adapt this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vwr93n2t/ to show the issue?